# "Ties Across The Channel"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

I have a question about the meaning of the preposition "*across*" [here](http://news.yahoo.com/france-britain-present-united-front-anger-soars-over-173522328.html#):

> Around 3,000 people from Africa, the Middle East and Asia are camped in Calais hoping to smuggle themselves into Britain, and the costly crisis has strained ***ties across the Channel***.

Definition 1-3 of this [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/across) for the preposition "across" reads:

> 3:  in every part of (a country, region, etc.)

So, the bold sentence fragment in the article loosely means "*ties in every part of the Channel*"?

Comment: Nope. Try definition 1b instead of 3: _on the other side of (something)_.

Comment: @J.R. But ties requires two parties, and therefore two "*sides*".  Definition 1b in this context only refers to one side.

Comment: You're not asking about _ties_, you're asking about _across_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ties across the channel" refers here to ties (chiefly) between France and Britain. These two nations reside on different sides of the [English Channel/*Manche*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Channel). Any ties or connections between these two countries must [span](http://thefreedictionary.com/span) this water and the word "across" is used to express this; that the connections go from one side to the other.

Comment: So, "*fights across the channel*" could never mean "*fight all over the channel*"?

Comment: "Channel" is used somewhat figuratively here. "Across" does not mean "all over" but much more simply "on both sides". So "fights across the channel" could possibly refer to fighting occurring (for the sake of argument) on the north and south sides. In contrast, if you need to refer to an event in the body of water known as the channel, you would need to use "in". "*The fighting happened in the English Channel*".

Answer (score 1):

In the English-speaking world, *channel* implicitly refers to the English Channel. Indeed, the ODO provides this meaning among the [primary senses](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/channel) of the word:

> (**the Channel**) The English Channel

Thus, *ties across the channel* refers to ties between the peoples and institutions on either side of the English Channel, especially between the governments of the United Kingdom and of France. More broadly, *cross-channel relations* can refer to the relationship of the UK to all of continental Europe, and to bodies based there like the European Union.

---

Similarly, *[the pond](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pond)* is a lighthearted reference to the Atlantic Ocean, referencing that transatlantic ties are so close, and interaction so commonplace, and modern transportation and communication so efficient, that even a vast ocean seems but a mere pond. I would go so far as to say that it refers primarily to the British-American "[Special Relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Relationship)"; if an American journalist writes about *our friends across the pond*, she means the Brits, who nearly crushed us militarily twice, and not the French, who saved us from the Brits the first time around.

Other geographic and hydrographic features are more ambiguous, and more dependent on current events and local context. *The Cape* means something different in Cape Town and Boston; *the Bay* in Toronto is not the same as *the Bay* in Baltimore. To Americans, *the Gulf* usually refers to the Gulf of Mexico (e.g. *the Gulf Coast*, *the Gulf spill*) except when the context is international politics, when it is almost invariably the Persian Gulf (*the Gulf War*, *the Gulf states*), or the location of a recent flareup (the [Gulf of Tonkin](http://nsarchive.gwu.edu/NSAEBB/NSAEBB132/tapes.htm), the [Gulf of Sidra](http://theaviationist.com/2014/01/04/f-14-vs-mig-23-1989/)).

Similarly, publications which refer to *[cross-strait relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Strait_relations)* usually mean the Taiwan Strait (or Formosa Strait), which separates the territory controlled by the People's Republic of China from that controlled by the Republic of China (Taiwan). I cannot say as to whether it defaults to something else in SIngapore or Gibraltar.

Comment: So, "*fights across the channel*" could never mean "*fight all over the channel*"?

Comment: @meatie What is the context? *Channel* has multiple meanings, so of course there are cases where *across the channel* can mean *all over the channel*, but it is unlikely to bethe case where *channel* refers to the geographic feature.